# Regular Expression for Titlecasing Booktitles (python)

Tags: python, regex

I'm creating a library catalog, including a form where users can add books to the catalog by inputting title, author name, etc.  Naturally I don't trust users to properly capitalize names and book titles, so I'm trying to write a function that will catch and fix capitalization errors. For instance, "harry potter and the goblet of fire" should become "Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire."  A particularly tricky part of this has been NOT matching and capitalizing trivial words (the, and, of, etc).  I've been able to find a few regular expressions that make this happen; however, a persistent bug with all of them has been situations where those words *should* be capitalized, such as at the beginning of a title or after a parenthesis, for example "slaughterhouse-five (the children's crusade)" should become "Slaughterhouse-Five (The Children's Crusade)" but everything I've tried returns "Slaughterhouse-Five (the Children's Crusade)" (in this case "the" should be capitalized).

I'm working in python, and the expressions I've tried so far include:

```
r"[A-Za-z]+[^\W+(and|of|the)\W+]"

r"[A-Za-z]+[^\s+(and|of|the)\s+]"

r"(?!and|the|of)[A-Za-z]+"
```

All of these work great for not capitalizing "and", "the", "of" in normal situations, but I need a way to make an exception to the exception so that "(the Children's Crusade)" becomes "(The Children's Crusade)".  If there is a way to only pass over trivial words if they are preceded by a whitespace (so that "Harry Potter *and the*" does not match "and the" because there are whitespaces before the trivial words but "(The Children's Crusade)" is matched because there is no whitespace before "the") I think that would solve my problem, but the way I would think to do that is already listed above.  Is there a better way to exclude words that are trivial *and* preceded by a whitespace?

Comment: Groups are not active in character classes. The regex `[^(and)]` will match any character except for "a","n","d",")" or "(". Example: `re.search('[^(and)]+','danny boy').group()`-->'y boy'

Answer (score 0):

If the only exceptions are cases where a whitespace is followed by one of "and", "the" or "of", then i would try this:

```
import re
def cap(x):
    if x.group('ex'):
        return x.group('ex')
    else:
        return x.group().capitalize()

#Test:    
s1="harry potter and the goblet of fire"
s2="slaughterhouse-five (the children's crusade)"

print(re.sub('(?P<ex> and| the| of)|[a-zA-Z]+',cap,s1))
print(re.sub('(?P<ex> and| the| of)|[a-zA-Z]+',cap,s2))
```

Output:

```
"Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire"
"Slaughterhouse-Five (The Children'S Crusade)"
```

Explanation:

- `cap` is the function to be used as a **repl** argument in the `re.sub` function
- `'(?P<ex> and| the| of)|[a-zA-Z]+'` catches either the group named "ex" ("and" or "the" or "of", preceded by a whitespace) or any other word.
- `x.group()` is the matched substring

But if there is a comma before the "and" and you don't want this "and" to be capitalized as well, the previous solution won't do:

```
s3='harry potter and the goblet of fire,and somthing else'
print(re.sub('(?P<ex> and| the| of)|[a-zA-Z]+',cap,s3))
```

Output:

```
"Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire,And Somthing Else"
```

However, this can be done using a different and more customizable approach:

```
def cap(x):
    if x.group() in ('and','the','of'):
        s=x.string
        i=x.span()[0]-1
        if s[i] in (' ',','):
            return x.group()
    return x.group().capitalize()

s3='harry potter and the goblet of fire,and something else'
print(re.sub('[a-zA-Z]+',cap,s3))
```

Thus, any word is caught and processed using the `cap` function, which, if necessary, can get the position of the word (`x.span`) in the original string (`x.string`).

P.S.1 There may be other exceptions and rules that should be added to the `cap` function.

P.S.2 If you found any flaws in the presented code, please tell.

Comment: To my eyes (which are very inexperienced in regex) I think the first solution you gave should work, since generally book titles don't do things like "Title,And Something Else" where there is no whitespace, but having the second solution as a backup just in case is appreciated.  I'll try this out and let you know if it works!  Thank you for the answer!